# Failed to deploy analysis services tabular project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ssas-tabular

I am unable to deploy analysis service tabular model from VS 2019. The error message returned is "1500 is not a valid value for this element.". Also I checked the deployment analysis server in SSMS to find the supported compatibility levels does not include 1500 (the maximum level it supports is 1480 and the default one is 1200). I'm not sure if it has to do with the issue. Could someone be able to help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to deploy a tabular model with a compatibility mode of 1500 (The latest version of Tabular) to an instance of that is will only support a compatibility mode of 1480, which I think is a SQL Server 2019 Analysis Services CTP2.X instance. Here are some details of the [compatibility modes options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/compatibility-level-for-tabular-models-in-analysis-services) and how to set them

You will have to do one of two things. But it will be dependent on the features used in the Data Model.
If you are using for example an SSAS 2019 feature like calculation groups in your data model you will have to update the SSAS instance from the CTP to the RTM release.

If you are not using any features in your data model that are compatibility mode 1500, you can [set your compatibility mode](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4214/how-to-change-compatibility-level-of-a-ssas-tabular-database-using-ssdt/) to 1400 in your data model

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much.  Really appreciate your time!